# Finding the rank of matrix that has a parameter

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, gaussian-elimination

> Find the rank of the following matrix. $$A_\lambda = \begin{pmatrix} 2\lambda &-1&2\\ -2&1+\lambda&2-3\lambda\\ -3&-1&5
> \end{pmatrix}$$

When finding the rank of matrix, I am allowed to use elementary row and column operations. But I am not sure if I can multiply by $\lambda$. I want to reduce this to an upper triangular matrix, but I always fail. Can you help me with the thinking process when solving this kind of problems?

After reducing it to triangular, the number of non-zero elements is the rank of the matrix.

Comment: When $\lambda=0$ you have full rank; when $\lambda \neq 0$ you can multiply by $\lambda$

Comment: @cdipaolo that was what i thought

Comment: @cdipaolo Please, consider turning your comment into an answer.

Comment: @SergioParreiras even with multiplying with lambda i cant solve this

Comment: If $\lambda=1$, would you be able to solve this?

Comment: @SergioParreiras yes

Comment: @SergioParreiras at least i think so

Comment: I don't think multiplying with $\lambda $ would help! Instead, you can eliminate $\lambda $ from certain terms by elementary Row column operations! For eg - To eliminate the $\lambda $ from the term $a_{22}$ You may use $C_2 \rightarrow C_2 +\frac{C_3}{3} $.

Comment: @CreepAnonymous thanks

Comment: @SergioParreiras i just figured out that i wouldnt know and that is the why i am not able to solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org):

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> t = Symbol('t')
>>> A = Matrix([[ 2*t,  -1,     2],
                [  -2, 1+t, 2-3*t],
                [  -3,  -1,     5]])
```

Computing the determinant as a function of $t$:

```
>>> simplify(A.det())
4*t**2 + 11*t + 6
```

Finding for which values of $t$ the determinant vanishes:

```
>>> solve(4*t**2 + 11*t + 6,t)
[-2, -3/4]
```

For $t=-2$ we obtain a rank-$2$ matrix:

```
>>> A.subs(t,-2)
Matrix([[-4, -1, 2],
        [-2, -1, 8],
        [-3, -1, 5]])
>>> A.subs(t,-2).rank()
2
```

For $t=-\frac 34$ we obtain another rank-$2$ matrix:

```
>>> A.subs(t,-Rational(3,4))
Matrix([[-3/2,  -1,    2],
        [  -2, 1/4, 17/4],
        [  -3,  -1,    5]])
>>> A.subs(t,-Rational(3,4)).rank()
2
```

For other values of $t$, the rank is $3$, of course.